# Assignig server side loop variable to client side array

Tags: javascript, vb.net, google-maps-api-3

**Update**
Sir this is current code of my web page.I made changes according to ur suggesstion but title is invisible or not displaying what has missed by me

```
  <script runat=server>

      Dim mgps As New Text.StringBuilder

      Public ReadOnly Property GPS() As String
          Get
              Return mgps.ToString

          End Get
      End Property
      Dim station As New Text.StringBuilder
      Public ReadOnly Property STA() As String
          Get
              Return station.ToString

          End Get
      End Property

  </script>  

  <%  Dim con As New OleDbConnection
      con = New OleDbConnection("Data Source=sml; User ID=sml; Password=sml; provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")
      con.Open()
      Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select STA_NAME, GPS_ONE from GPS", con)

      Dim ds As New DataSet
      Dim I As Long

      Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
      da.Fill(ds, "GPS")
      mgps.AppendLine("[")
      For I = 0 To ds.Tables("GPS").Rows.Count - 1
          '   mgps.AppendLine("new google.maps.LatLng(" & ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE") & "),")
          mgps.AppendLine("{GPS:new google.maps.LatLng(" & ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE") & "), Sta_Name:'" & STA & "'},")
      Next I
      mgps.AppendLine("];")

      con.Close()
      %>
```

**Update2**
And JS code is here

```
  for(i=0; i<GPS.length; i++)
{

      var image = 'ico/no.png';
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var ContentString = GPS[i].TITLE
      markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker(
      { 
       position: GPS[i].GPS,
       map: map,
       draggable:true,
       icon:image,
       title:GPS[i].TITLE

       });                       
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(ContentString);
        infowindow.open(map,markers[i]);
        });


}
```

Sir My infowindow is not opening what may the issue

Comment: what does the data in GPS_ONE look like in your GPS table?

Comment: It looks like this 30.302631872323,73.084871561209

Comment: then as per my answer below, it looks like you're missing the new google.maps.LatLng( part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how you're storing data in your GPS_ONE column in your GPS table, but if your for loop looks like this:

```
for(i=0; i<GPS.length-1; i++)
{

      var image = 'ico/no.png';
      markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker(
      { 
       position: GPS[i],
       map: map,
       draggable:true,
       icon:image,
       title: (i+1) + GPS //why is this here? do you have two variables with the same name or did you mean GPS[i]?
       });                             
}
```

and the data in your GPS_ONE column looks like this:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(31.204549793299,72.264183974237)
```

then what you wrote should be working.

EDIT: it looks like you're not creating an array of google map latlng objects as per your example above.  Try changing your loop in your vb to look like this:

```
    For I = 0 To ds.Tables("GPS").Rows.Count - 1
        mgps.AppendLine("new google.maps.LatLng(" & ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE") & "),")
    Next I
```

EDIT for second question:
You can store everything in a JSON object, so

```
    For I = 0 To ds.Tables("GPS").Rows.Count - 1
        mgps.AppendLine("{GPS:new google.maps.LatLng(" & ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE") & "), Title:'" & titleColumnSourceHere & "'},")
    Next I
```

Then you can use this JSON object like this:

```
for(i=0; i<GPS.length-1; i++)
{

      var image = 'ico/no.png';
      markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker(
      { 
       position: GPS[i].GPS,
       map: map,
       draggable:true,
       icon:image,
       title: GPS[i].Title
       });                             
}
```

Obviously I would recommend renaming your GPS variable to something more suitable because it now holds non-gps data

Comment: You can create an object that contains all your data, but for simplicity's sake, just make a second array with title info. They should be the same size because they're coming from the same data source, so just adding Title[i] where title is (assuming you name your variable Title, and do all the other stuff you did last time)

Comment: sure, I just added it to my answer

Comment: you have title:GPS[i].STA but the object you're creating is Sta_Name so do title:GPS[i].Sta_Name

Comment: mgps.AppendLine("{GPS:new google.maps.LatLng(" & ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE") & "), Sta_Name:'" & ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("STA_NAME") & "'},")

Comment: Sir will u please check my update2 because my infowindow is not opening o map